# Toggle click function of a anchor after click

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change which onclick javascript function is executed after an anchor is clicked?

Example:

```
<a id="myLocation" class="locator" href="#" onclick="javascript:getMyLocation();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;My Location</a>
```

When the user clicks this anchor their location is displayed on a map with a marker.

I want the onclick to change to RemoveLocation() now so that when they click the anchor again is removes the marker for their location on the map.

getMyLocation() and RemoveLocation are already written I just need to change the onclick event after a user clicks the anchor, if possible.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can use `$.toggle()`

Comment: @NADH: That only works for visibility.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, that's a different toggle. You can do `$('#selector').toggle(function() { alert('a'); }, function() { alert('b'); });`

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Oh, woops. Right. However, the OP hasn't specified that he's using jQuery so I don't think this is a solution regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `getMyLocation()` function:

```
document.getElementById("myLocation").onclick = RemoveLocation;
```

And in the `RemoveLocation()` function:

```
document.getElementById("myLocation").onclick = getMyLocation;
```

Comment: Be aware that you're invoking the functions rather than passing them as references.

Comment: That is correct, my mistake. The `()` should be removed to avoid this, editing to correct.

Comment: It has happened to everyone :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible!

You just need to reassign the event handler for the click event on that element.

Something like:

```
function getMyLocation() {

    ...

    document.getElementById("myLocation").onclick = RemoveLocation;
}


function RemoveLocation() {

    ...

    document.getElementById("myLocation").onclick = getMyLocation;
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery, see the [toggle event function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)